# convert custom set data structure to list java

Tags: java, list, data-structures, collections, set

I was just wondering whether it was possible to convert a data structure (in my case a set) that I created from scratch to a list.

I've read around (on the Internet and on here) and seen that it is possible to convert a set to a list by doing the following:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
set.add(1);
set.add(2);

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(set);
```

But I was wondering if it was possible to do this without the use of HashSet as I've created my own immutable Set data structure (I have an abstract class called Set, a class that defines the Empty set and a class that defines a set that has elements), or if it is impossible.

In my class I have a method called toList() which I've tried to implement as:

```
public List<T> toList() {
   return new ArrayList(this);
}
```

I thought that when used in a program it would work like the method above by taking the set and making a list version of it.

But I realise that my set isn't a `HashSet<Integer>` it would be `Empty<Integer>` which gives me a problem. It says that the constructor is undefined for this, which is understandable as it is a "custom" class and so java.util.ArrayList would not have accommodated for this.

So my question is: is there any way to convert this immutable data structure from a set of Empty to an ArrayList or should I use a HashSet instead?

Comment: your custom class implements the java class Set? or your own custom Set?

Comment: It's my own custom set

Comment: You could write a method that takes one of your sets and returns an array list. This way you don't need to implement Collection.

Comment: @chatton I think that's what I was trying to do by having the toList() method return new ArrayList<T>(set) but that kept giving me an error

Comment: That's because an array list doesn't take one of your sets as an argument. Try making a new array list,  then add each element from your set to it. And return that

Comment: @chatton aah ok that makes perfect sense, thank you

Answer (score 2):

As per the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)) the constructor of `ArrayList` requires an object that implements `Collection` interface. So, you can make your Set `class` implement Collection interface.

However, doing this means you will have to implement lot of methods. If you don't want to do this then, java already provides [AbstractCollection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) class. Here's what the javadoc reads:

> This class provides a skeletal implementation of the Collection
>   interface, to minimize the effort required to implement this
>   interface.

So, instead of implementing `Collection` interface, you can `extend` AbstractCollection class and override `iterator` and `size` methods only.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use constructor if your custom set implements `java.util.Collection` interface.

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined your custom Set class to implement the Collection interface then you can do what you are trying to do.  Basically as you can see all of the Collections in the Java Standard Library implement that interface.  If you implement that interface as well Arraylist will be able to use the new ArrayList constructor.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

By the way all you have to do is implement the toArray() method in order to get new ArrayList<> to work.  You can leave the rest unimplemented.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray--

Comment: Ah, ok - I thought I'd also have to implement all the other methods from the Collection interface, but I'll try this out - thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your custom set data structure needs to implement [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), in order to be accepted by the constructor of ArrayList.

Per the ArrayList [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> ArrayList(Collection c)
>   Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order, they are returned by the collection's iterator.

An easy way would be to extend `AbstractCollection` which already implements `Collection` interface:

```
class CustomSet extends AbstractCollection {

    @Override
     public size() {
      // your implementation
      }

    @Override
     public iterator() {
      // your implementation
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I've seen everyone comment to implement Collection so I will do this and see. I'll also try extending AbstractCollection and see what happens. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create an empty ArrayList and add all elements to it?

```
public List<T> toList() {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    forEach(list::add);
    return list;
}
```